# Print, loop, Indentation, Python

Tags: python-2.7, loops, indentation

I need a pit of help. I am currently learning python, and I have python 2.7.8
I am looking to build a simple program that will help to count the vowels in my word.
Here is the code:

```
count = 0
total = 0
for v in "bonbon":
  count += 1
  if v == 'e' or v == 'o' or v == 'u' or v == 'a':
    print('the number of vowel in your word is ' +str(total))
```

Why does it print twice?
1- the number of my vowel is 0
and then the number of my is 2

Could someone help me please?
Thanks guys

Comment: For future questions, inspect the toolbar above the text field when you ask/edit a question. There is a code block button marked with `{}`. If you select your code and click this button it is automatically correctly indented, and displayed correctly in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's printing twice because you have the print inside of the for loop. You should instead increment total inside the for loop and then print it afterwards. If you do:

```
count = 0
total = 0
for v in "bonbon":
  count += 1
  if v == 'e' or v == 'o' or v == 'u' or v == 'a':
    total += 1

print('the number of vowel in your word is ' + str(total))
```

It should work.

Comment: I would suggest to check wheter a letter is a vowel or not in a more pythonic way, namely ``if v in 'aeiouAEIOU':``

Comment: Thank you so much.Its sorted now

Comment: Just don't know how to do it/ dont really use this site